# string to byte then byte[] 0xformat

Tags: java, string, arrays, byte

I am having problems of conversion through string->byte->byte[]

What I have done so far:

```
     double db = 1.00;
     double ab = db*100;
     int k = (int) ab;

     String aa = String.format("%06d", k);

     String first = aa.substring(0,2);``
     String second = aa.substring(2,4);
     String third = aa.substring(4,6);

     String ff = "0x"+first;
     String nn = "0x"+second;
     String yy = "0x"+third;
```

I want to write those bytes to an byte[]. What I mean is:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[]{(byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x68, (byte) 0x14,
    (byte) 0x93, (byte) 0x01, ff,nn,yy};
```

in this order and casted with 0x's. Any help is greatly appriciated.

Regards,
Ali

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Byte.decode()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29)

> Decodes a String into a Byte. Accepts decimal, hexadecimal, and octal numbers given by the following grammar:

```
DecodableString:
    Signopt DecimalNumeral 
    Signopt 0x HexDigits 
    Signopt 0X HexDigits 
    Signopt # HexDigits 
    Signopt 0 OctalDigits
```

Below code will print `10`, `11` which is value of `0XA`, `0XB`

```
    byte[] temp = new byte[2];
    temp[0] = Byte.decode("0xA");
    temp[1] = Byte.decode("0xB");
    System.out.println(temp[0]);
    System.out.println(temp[1]);
```

Comment: is it going to decode my string again to bytes? I mean those strings are really what I want.

Comment: actually my project works without convert them into bytes again. I just wanted to put those strings on bytearray. thats it.

Comment: So you mean you want to convert again it to Hex from Byte? If you want again String then you can Use `Integer.toHexString()`

Comment: basically my output is, let me say 11 as string.

I want to convert it to an integer 0x11 to be able to put into byte[].

I mean int String SS = 11;
int hex1 = 0xSS;

which is 0x11.

Comment: that is not possible you can not put string in byte array. you can only put bytes in byte array

Comment: Ok I got what I need. But now I have another problem, how can I add 0x to in front of an integer to be able to use it in byte array?

Comment: You don't need to just cast it using (byte)

Comment: I need it because the device only understands this way. I have my integer. let me say 11, I have to convert it to 0x11. by simply casting it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

As I see, the main question here is how to convert a 2 char String representing a hexa number to a byte type. The Byte class has a static method parseByte(String s, int radix) that can parse a String to number using the radix you want (in this case, 16). Here is an example of how you can do the parsing and save the result in a byte array:

```
public static void main(String [] args){
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(getBytes("0001020F")));
}


public static byte[] getBytes(String str) {

    byte [] result = new byte[str.length() / 2]; //assuming str has even number of chars...

    for(int i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
        int startIndex = i * 2;
        result[i] = Byte.parseByte(str.substring(startIndex, startIndex + 2), 16);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: please consider adding some small explanation as to what your code is doing (see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers).

Comment: Sorry for taking long, I just added an explanation