# Convert usb command to byte array

Tags: android, byte

I try to send command to USB device. I have to convert this command : DA AD 02 74 00 BFDB to byte array. I started like this :

```
private static final byte[] send = new byte[] {
            (byte)0xda,(byte)0xad, // const
            // command

    };
```

But I don't know what's next. How should I write 02 as a byte, 74 and so on ? Please, help.

Comment: As you are; `,(byte)0x02,(byte)0x74, ..., (byte)0xdb`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just continue the same way you did before:

```
private static final byte[] send = new byte[] {
    (byte)0xDA, (byte)0xAD, (byte)0x02, (byte)0x74,
    (byte)0x00, (byte)0xBF, (byte)0xDB
};
```

To simplify the syntax, you could also take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12391479/1871033) and then use a string like `"DAAD027400BFDB"` or even improve the code from that answer to ignore spaces, so you can keep the syntax you had in your question.